# Algorithm to determine which slides are next to the center in an infinite rotating carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, sorting, math

So, I have built an infinite rotating carousel of 10 items:

```
[one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten]
```

The list wraps and displays five items at a time. The list is centered on the "active" item, and by default starts at one.

**So the default view is:**

```
[nine, ten, one, two, three]
```

The list can be scrolled in either direction. If the default view was scrolled to the right, the new view would be:

```
[ten, one, two, three, four]
```

If the default view was scrolled to the left, the new view would be:

```
[eight, nine, ten, one, two]
```

And so on.

I need a way of targeting the two elements on the outermost edges of the view. In the case of the default view, it would be `nine` and `three`. But because the elements wrap all the way around, the conditions needed are confusing to me.

Think of each element as a class, which will determine its "edgy-ness" internally.

Each element has available to it:

```
1. own index (eg 1)
2. active slide (eg 3)
3. number of slides (eg 10)
```

Given these numbers, it must be possible to determine if an element is on an edge, right? How can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so the active slide is the center one. Let's just call that `var active = 1`;

Left slide is `active - 2` and right slide is `active + 2`, except of course the fact that it wraps.

You can use 'modulus' to help. right slide is `var right (active + 2) % 10`, so when active is 9, that gives you 11 % 10 which is 1, which is correct, `[7,8,9,10,1]`

for the left side, I would do `var left = active - 2; if (left < 1) left = 10-left`

edit >>

For the left side, I would keep using `%` modulus operator, like so: `var left = ((active - 2) + 10) % 10`

Comment: You can do the left side also with modulus: `left = (active - 2 + n) % n`. The `+n` in the middle makes sure that the operand never drops below zero.

Comment: So you'd use modular arithmetic at one end of the range and an `if` statement at the other end of the range ?

Comment: You can also do the right side with an if: `var right = active + 2; if (right > n) right = right - n;`

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark at the time of making this answer, I *tried* doing modular at the lower end, (-1 % 10) and it didn't give me what I was expecting. After reading your response, I thought a bit harder about how to do it and realized I should have suggested `((active - 2) + 10) % 10`

Answer (score 2):

Denote by `n` the number of slides, by `k` the number slides you can view at a time and by `i` the active slide. In your case:

```
n=10, k=5
```

Then:

```
right = (i + k/2 + n) % n
left  = (i - k/2 + n) % n
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not actually *perform* the rotation by mutating the array?

Here is a small demo where the items are just strings:

```js
var data = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten'];

function rotate(data, output, steps) {
    // Make steps a positive value
    steps = (steps + data.length) % data.length;
    // perform the rotation on the array
    data.push(...data.splice(0, steps));
    // Display the first 5 values from the array
    output.textContent = JSON.stringify(data.slice(0, 5));
}

left.onclick = rotate.bind(null, data, output, -1);
right.onclick = rotate.bind(null, data, output, 1);
// Output initial situation
output.textContent = JSON.stringify(data.slice(0, 5));
```

```html
<button id="left">&lt;</button><button id="right">&gt;</button>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

With this way of working the active value is always at index 2.

Answer (score 0):

As a first draft thought, assuming that you have access only to the 3 numbers you mentioned, i would just add some if statements to check if an element is on the edge.

```
//define the left and right edge -----------

int right_edge = element.active_slide + 2;   //+2 only if you show 5 slides
int left_edge = element.active_slide - 2;    //-2 only if you show 5 slides

if( right_edge > element.number_of_slides ){
   right_edge = right_edge - element.number_of_slides;
} 
if( left_edge == 0 ){
   left_edge = element.number_of_slides;  //=10    
}
if( left_edge < 0 ){
   left_edge = element.number_of_slides + left_edge;  
}



// check if current element is one of the edges

if( ( element.own_index == left.edge ) || ( element.own_index == right_edge ) ){
   //the element is an edge, do whatever is needed
}
else{
    //the element is not an edge
}
```

of course this is just a quick thought, to show you a way it can be done. It is also not written in the most appropriate form, using a modulo for example could serve you better